# Configuring a dockerfile to 'read' from a directory?

Tags: python, docker, flask, dockerfile

I am building a webapp (a simple flask site) that uses docker. I want my development code to not reside within docker, but be executed by the development environment (using python3) I have defined in my dockerfile. I know that I can use the `COPY . .` syntax in a dockerfile to copy my source code into the image for execution, but that violates my aim of separating the container from my source. Is there a way to have a docker container read and execute the code that it is in the directory I run the `docker container run` command from?

Right now my container uses the copy company to copy all the source code into the container. It then uses the `CMD` command to automatically run the flask app:

```
CMD [ "python", "flask_app/server.py" ]
```

(I'm storing all my flask code in a directory called `flask_app`). I'm assuming this works because all this has been copied into the container (according to the specifications given in the dockerfile) and is being executed when I run the container. I would like for the container to instead access and execute `flask_app/server.py` without copying this information into itself -- is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: You can mount your code of your host onto the container using the `--volume /HOST/PATH:/CONTAINER_PATH` option of `docker run`. Apart from this, would it make sense to just have a development dockerfile and a production dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `COPY` to move the code into the container, you'll use a "bind mount" (https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/).

When you run the container, you'll do it with a command like this:

```
docker run --mount type=bind,source=<path_outside_container>,target=<path_inside_container> <image_tag>
```

For portability, I recommending putting this line in a script intended to be run from the repository root, and having the `<path_outside_container>` be `"$(pwd)"`, so that it will work on other people's computers. You'll need to adjust `<path_inside_container>` and your `CMD` depending on where you want the code to live inside the container.

(Obviously you can also put whatever other options you'd like on the command, like `--it --rm` or `-p <whatever>`.)

Comment: Thank you so much -- this worked! I'll be using this going forward!